# PHP script silently crashes while downloading a file via Net_SFTP

Tags: php, phpseclib

I have a script that downloads 2 files from 2 different servers. During the download, the page will either stop loading, or produce a 500 Internal Server Error. The timing is inconsistent, and there are no error logs anywhere. I can see the files downloading if I refresh the server's folder in my FTP client. I even had the web hosting company turn on all error logging but there is zero errors. The files are XML, and their sizes are between 7MB and 15MB.

This is the script that runs twice:

```
$conn_id = new Net_SFTP($ftp_server . ":2222");
$conn_id->setTimeout(false);

if (!$conn_id->login($ftp_user_name, $ftp_user_pass))
    exit('Login Failed');

$conn_id->get($server_file, $local_file);
$status = 'success';
$output =  file_get_contents($local_file);

unset($conn_id);
```

Also, does the get command return a boolean?

Update: I contacted my hosting company, and they had this to say:

*For 500 errors, we must look them up. You were getting the following error:
"Premature end of script headers"
Which is the unix version of we don't know.*

Comment: I had some problems a while back when refreshing the folder with 'can't access file, file in use'. I don't know if this is your problem though. Can you close the folder and execute the script again?

Comment: even if you tailf /var/log/httpd/access_log or error_log? there is no result?

Comment: I only have FTP and Cpanel access.

Comment: I updated my question to have the response from the hosting company's support.

Answer (score 0):

```
$conn_id = new Net_SFTP($ftp_server . ":2222");
```

That's not the correct way to do it. You're supposed to do it like this:

```
$conn_id = new Net_SFTP($ftp_server, 2222);
```

What you're doing is analogous to this:

```
fsockopen($ftp_server . ':2222', 22);
```

Comment: Thank you, however I am still getting an internal server error after making this change.

Comment: Looking at your `$conn_id->setTimeout(false);`...  that's wrong too. false gets cast to 0 so you're essentially telling `stream_select` to return instantly. See http://php.net/stream-select . It advises against setting the timeout to 0. If you're trying to make it so it doesn't timeout you can't do that, but you can set a timeout that's really high. Like an hour or a day or a week or some such.

Comment: OK I changed that to *60*60*, or 1 hour. I also updated my question to have the response from the hosting company's support.

Comment: @Jack Cole - I think this is applicable to you (assuming it isn't you that posted that lol): https://github.com/phpseclib/phpseclib/issues/646